# how to send a bit larger set of data with $http.get?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, httprequest, getmethod

I was able to send data through `params` but when I tried to send more bigger data, it threw the error such as `url characters exceeded`. So, I want to send those data to the body and get it from the C# method using `[FromBody]` or without frombody. The code below is the working version using params, but I can't find the working version of using `data` in the `angularjs` and `[FromBody]` in the method.

**list of regions**

```
[{id:1, name:"test"}]
```

**http request**

```
 return $http.get("api/region/getlocalities", { params: { regions: sendingRegions }, paramSerializer: '$httpParamSerializerJQLike' }).then(function (x) {
                        return x.data;
         });
```

**method**

```
      [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/region/getlocalities")]
        public IEnumerable<Locality> GetLocalities([FromUri]List<Region> regions)
        {
            return _customZoneService.GetLocalities(regions);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All browsers have some limit for URL length (IE 2000 e.g.). If you need to send GET with long URL... you must switch to POST and send data in body instead.